# How exactly cron works?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, cron

I want to implement a simple C++ class that parses a cron entry and executes a task on specified schedule. Wiki says cron have implemented following algorithm:

1. On start-up, look for a file named .crontab in the home directories of all account holders.
2. For each crontab file found, determine the next time in the future that each command must run.
3. Place those commands on the Franta–Maly event list with their corresponding time and their "five field" time specifier.
4. Enter main loop:

   - **Examine the task entry at the head of the queue, compute how far in the future it must run.**
   - Sleep for that period of time.
     On awakening and after verifying the correct time, execute the task at the head of the queue (in background) with the privileges of the user who created it.
   - Determine the next time in the future to run this command and place it back on the event list at that time value.

I'm only interested in the bold part. Given current time (`2015-11-07 14:48:03`) and a cron entry (`0 0 * * 1 *`) how can I determine the time distance (seconds) to the upcoming execution point?

Comment: Does [`std::chrono`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono)'s reference documentation help?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ No. I know how to wait for some duration. The problem is calculating that duration. For example How can I know home many seconds are to nex Friday 12:00 PM for example.

Comment: Well, `std::chrono::duration` was exactly designed for this.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Whell, there is no such API for that.

Comment: There is too `operator-` taking two `time_point`s and returning `duration`. There's `duration_cast` for converting a duration to different units of time. In what way is this insufficient?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Seems I couldn't explain the problem clearly: How can you calculate the time point (`std::chrono::system_clock::time_point`) corresponding to the next execution point, specified by a cron entry like `0 0 * 4 5 *` (Every Wednesday of March at 12:00 PM)? So that you can take current time_point and subtract next time_point from it to get sleep duration...

Comment: `std::chrono` doesn't support that. It's a timing library, it's not a calendaring library. Perhaps you can find a third-party library for that, or else you'll have to, you know, write some code.